# using strtok to parse command line args in c++

Tags: c++, strtok

I'm trying to parse command line args with strtok. I get one successful token before I enter a loop but once I enter my while loop to tokenize the rest of my args, it quits working Any ideas? code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char *t = NULL;
t = strtok(*argv," ,.-");
while (t != NULL)
{
    cout << t << endl;
    t = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the string you're tokenizing that fails? "ABC DEF" works fine for me. As it does when separated by , . or -

Comment: imo, strtok should never be used in C++. It's one of the ugliest functions in C.

Comment: I'm writing a shell program so I'm testing with "ls -l"

Comment: On my platform, the first string is the executable path. Also, "-" is in your token and your list of separators. But yes, teaching strtok in C++ is... sad.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way strtok works. Subsequent calls to strtok will continue to process the first argument that was supplied in the first call. strtok shall not be used for this as the arguments already have been tokenized, i.e. they are not in one single char array.

Comment: I see. I went by the documentation from cplusplus.com, so maybe that was a mistake. Do you have any suggestions for how to tokenize my input?

Comment: Yes you should loop over the argv array elements and process them. No need for tokenization. You have size of array in argc.

Comment: I would like to, but I'm afraid strtok() is part of my assignment. Sucks that after reading a while I'm picking up that strtok is the spawn of satan

Comment: Yes particularly as it is not thread safe. You can use it to tokenize an individual command line argument at a time provided each argument needs to be tokenized. strtok is more C than C++ and not a function that should be focused on in school

Comment: +1 Answer is correct. To please your teacher you'll have to create a single string out of the command line and tokenize that. i.e. 'de-tokenize' it!